How to install tweenjs rotation plugin using npm?
I am using tweenjs in my web app. I install all dependencies using npm. I import tweenjs using
import * as TWEEN from '@tweenjs/tween.js';

Now I want to use the rotation plugin, but I can't figure out how to import it through npm.
https://createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/RotationPlugin.html
Does anyone know?
